glcoud logging read cli gives fewer results compared with logs explorer ui
I have a filter I'm using in both the gcloud logging read cli and the logs explorer ui, with the same date range, and I'm getting 1300 results from the ui, and just one from the cli. The date range is correct, as the one result I'm getting is one of the 1300.
UI Filter is like
resource.type=k8s_container
resource.labels.namespace_name=xxx
resource.labels.container_name=yyy
SEARCH("`ExecutionTime(ms)`")

cli command is:
gcloud logging read 'resource.type=k8s_container and resource.labels.container_name=yyy and timestamp>="2024-05-13T14:58:00Z" AND timestamp<="2024-05-13T15:01:00Z" and resource.labels.namespace_name=xxx and textPayload:"ExecutionTime(ms)"'
I've tried adding --limit=500 in case that was an issue. Not sure what else to try - they should come from the same source shouldn't they?

It's difficult to say what's going on here without seeing this 1 log entry next to any of the 1299 entries that are missing in the gcloud command output.
Also, can you retry by removing the quotations around ExecutionTime(ms) in textPayload:"ExecutionTime(ms)"?
Reference example

removing quotes gives
ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Right-hand side functions are currently not supported.
I guess because of () - changing it to ExecutionTime (no quotes) gives the same single result.  Not sure how best to share example output - it exceeds character limit here

Ah ha - solved by removing all the "and"s from the cl:
gcloud logging read 'resource.type=k8s_container resource.labels.namespace_name=yyy resource.labels.container_name=xxx textPayload:"ExecutionTime(ms)" (timestamp>="2024-05-13T14:58:00Z" timestamp<"2024-05-13T15:01:00Z")' 
Don't really understand why, but not going to worry too much, spent too long already!
